# I want to separate a string like below with id and value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```sql
DECLARE @ELEMENT1 VARCHAR(100)='REF*MK*37908-155-3**DO#0000000000#ZZ#202108161400PB3#ZZ#20210817BBBBBBB4';
```

and I want a answer like in below table

| Identity | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | REF |
| 2 | MK |
| 3 | 37908-155-3 |
| 4 |  |
| 5 | DO |
| 6 | 0000000000 |
| 7 | ZZ |
| 8 | 202108161400PB3 |
| 9 | ZZ |
| 10 | 20210817BBBBBBB4 |

```
DECLARE @ELEMENT1 VARCHAR(100)='REF*MK*37908-155-3**DO#0000000000#ZZ#202108161400PB3#ZZ#20210817BBBBBBB4';
;WITH Identities AS(
    SELECT [key] / 2 AS Entry,
           MAX(CASE WHEN [key] % 2 = 0 THEN [Value] END) AS [Identity],
           MAX(CASE WHEN [key] % 2 = 1 THEN [Value] END) AS [Value]
    FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('["',REPLACE(@ELEMENT1,'#', '","'),'"]')) OJ
    GROUP BY [key] / 2)
SELECT TOP (2)
       [Identity],
       [Value]
FROM Identities
ORDER BY Entry ASC
```

Comment: You need to replace more than just `#`, you need to `REPLACE`  all your delimiters. In your example, that looks like both `*`,  and `#`.

Comment: I agree @Larnu..But I am not able to handle both delimiters in the condition

Comment: The semicolon is a statement **terminator**. Stop using it as a "beginator" which is a lazy kludge to avoid properly terminating ALL your statements. And use of TOP without an order by clause is logical nonsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace all of your delimiters, not just one of them. I additionally demonstrate the use of `TRANSLATE` here, in the event you have more than 2 delimiters, and therefore need to cater for them in the future:

```sql
DECLARE @ELEMENT1 VARCHAR(100)='REF*MK*37908-155-3**DO#0000000000#ZZ#202108161400PB3#ZZ#20210817BBBBBBB4';

SELECT OJ.[Key] + 1 AS [Identity], --Don't use reserved keywords as aliases/object names
       [value]
FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('["',REPLACE(TRANSLATE(@ELEMENT1,'#*','##'),'#', '","'),'"]')) OJ;
```

If you are on an Azure SQL Database (and *hopefully* SQL Server 2022+) you can make use of `STRING_SPLIT` and it's ordinal parameter instead:

```sql
DECLARE @ELEMENT1 VARCHAR(100)='REF*MK*37908-155-3**DO#0000000000#ZZ#202108161400PB3#ZZ#20210817BBBBBBB4';

SELECT ordinal AS [Identity], --Don't use reserved keywords as aliases/object names
       value
FROM STRING_SPLIT(TRANSLATE(@ELEMENT1,'#*','##'),'#',1) SS;
```

I don't use it without the ordinal parameter, as it's documented that `STRING_SPLIT` does not guarantee the order in which the data is returned. Although I (and many others) have never seen such the order *not* be respected, the fact that it's explicitly documented to not be, and you have to rely on arbitrary ordering, *could* result in incorrect results which you would have no control over. Fortunately, after 6 years of complaints, Microsoft have *finally* added the parameter to the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @ELEMENT1 VARCHAR(100) 
                  = 'REF*MK*37908-155-3**DO#0000000000#ZZ#202108161400PB3#ZZ#20210817BBBBBBB4';


SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) Id
     , d2.value
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@ELEMENT1 , '*') d1
 CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(d1.value , '#') d2
```